# Change of coordinates breaks the equality of mixed partial derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to reduce the PDE

$$u_{xx} + 2 u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0,$$
to its canonical form $u_{\eta \eta} = 0.$

According to the book that I'm using, $\epsilon (x,y) = y-x$ and $\eta (x,y) = x$ is a valid coordinate transformation, so lets use it.

After doing the algebra,

$$u_{xx} = -1[u_{\epsilon \epsilon} * (-1) + u_{\epsilon \eta }] + [(-1)* u_{\eta \epsilon} + u_{\eta \eta}],$$

$$u_{yy} = u_{\epsilon \epsilon}$$

$$u_{xy} = (-1)[(-1)u_{\epsilon \epsilon}] + [u_{\eta \epsilon}],$$
but $$u_{yx} = (-1) u_{\epsilon \epsilon} + u_{\epsilon \eta} \not = u_{xy}.$$

So, what is wrong in with this transformation ?, and why the mixed partials are not equal in $\epsilon, \eta$ coordinates ?

I mean, I plug everything into the PDE, by $u_{xy}$ does not transforms the PDE into its canonical form, but $u_{yx} $ does.

I checked my calculations, but I couldn't find an error either.

Comment: Where dd the extra factor of $-1$ in $u_{xy}$ come from?

Comment: @amd You are right, I that should be a plus! .Thanks a lot for pointing out. if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you’ve got a stray factor of $-1$ in your expression for $u_{xy}$.

We have $${\partial \over \partial x} = {\partial\epsilon \over \partial x}{\partial \over \partial\epsilon} + {\partial\eta \over \partial x}{\partial \over \partial\eta} = -{\partial \over \partial\epsilon} + {\partial \over \partial\eta} \\ {\partial \over \partial y} = {\partial\epsilon \over \partial y}{\partial \over \partial\epsilon}+{\partial\eta \over \partial y}{\partial \over \partial\eta} = {\partial \over \partial\epsilon}$$ so, assuming equality of mixed partials with respect to $\epsilon$ and $\eta$, $${\partial^2 \over \partial x \, \partial y} = \left(-{\partial \over \partial\epsilon} + {\partial \over \partial\eta}\right){\partial \over \partial\epsilon} = -{\partial^2 \over \partial\epsilon^2}+{\partial^2 \over \partial\eta\,\partial\epsilon} = -{\partial^2 \over \partial\epsilon^2}+{\partial^2 \over \partial\epsilon\,\partial\eta} = {\partial \over \partial\epsilon}\left(-{\partial \over \partial\epsilon} + {\partial \over \partial\eta}\right) = {\partial^2 \over \partial y \, \partial x}.$$